# How do I create a form in angular that merges a hyperlink to a string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, hyperlink

I'm learning angular and I'm trying to create a list of websites to click on, like how you would see on a bookmark app, from a todo example.

https://github.com/LightYear9/ToDoList

I added a new variable newURL in the index.html

```
input id="new-todo" placeholder="http://example.com" ng-model="newURL" ng-disabled="saving" autofocus
```

I can see it would go straight to the  js/controllers/todoctrl.js but I don't know how to work both strings from the same form into the

```
$scope.addTodo = function () {
```

to where I can just click on it as one like  a `href='#'` would do.

Much appreciated for any help

Comment: What *"both strings"*?

Comment: None of this makes sense.

Comment: Sorry that I'm not making any sense. I'm trying to type in a hyperlink with a description so I can create a list of links. I'm trying to do it based on this angularjs todo app http://todomvc.com/examples/angularjs/#/

Comment: so you are basically trying to navigate to the websites without having to use href and through controller??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To grab whatever the user inputs you can access newURL variable through $scope

```
//Array to hold urls 
$scope.booksList = [];

$scope.addTodo = function (url) {

//assign newURL to url in scope of this function..
url = $scope.newURL;

//Add url to books list
$scope.booksList.push(url)

}
```

**you will need to create a `<button>` of some sort and add ng-click="addTodo()" to it...**

Hope this helps